# Duplicated kernel page table entries

Tags: linux-kernel, paging

I wrote an application that outputs -only kernel- `page directory entries` and `page table entries` starting from CR3 of the current process

In the logs, I can see distinct PDEs with different PTEs (which is normal). However, I can see also that some PTEs (in the same PDE) all point to the same page table, this is repeated many time

example:

> [ 5437.670588] page_table: 4890000 global: 0 dirty: 1 u/s: 0
>   read/write: 1 present: 1
>
> [ 5437.670815] page_table: 4890000 global: 1 dirty: 0 u/s: 0
>   read/write: 1 present: 1

Here we can see they point to the same page table but, only the flag global is different

Does any one has an explanation for this ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's in that page table?

Comment: These are 2 PTEs that point to the same kernel page (code, data or code and data). I don't know exactly what is their content